# Clearinterval on mouse click or hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, hover, clearinterval

I have a fullscreen image slider which doesn’t have an autoplay functionality, so I had to write custom script to click on the next button.

Here it is

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {

document.querySelector('.fp-controlArrow.fp-next').click();


}, 7000);

setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( interval ); }, 44000);
```

**But now I’d love to clearInterval** whenever user clicks on the button of the same class (.fp-controlArrow.fp-next) . Can the JS distinguish the difference between simulated click and real mouse click somehow? If so, what would be the code for that?

And if not, maybe it is possible to clear interval on hovering the button with the .fp-controlArrow.fp-next class ?

Thanks!

Comment: I could not understand what you mean by "simulated click and real mouse click"? What is a simulated click?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can distinguish between a user generated event vs a code generated event by using **isTrusted** property of the event object in the event listener.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.fp-controlArrow.fp-next');

elem.addEventListener("click", function( event ) {   
    if(event.isTrusted)
        clearInterval(interval);

  }, false);
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mousedown` event for Real click.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.fp-controlArrow.fp-next')
el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    clearInterval( interval );
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fov47eny/

Also you can use `isTrusted` but it has limited support on browsers.

```
if (e.isTrusted) {
    /* The event is trusted. */
} else {
    /* The event is not trusted. */
}
```

Comment: Hi, Mohammad. Thanks for the answer. so in my case I should replace the “targer” with my button class is that right? so my code is as follows...where am I mistaking ?     `var interval = setInterval(function() {

document.querySelector('.fp-controlArrow.fp-next').click(); }, 7000);

$('.fp-controlArrow.fp-next').on('mousedown', function(){
  clearInterval( interval ); });`

Comment: @DmitryRa I updated my code. You can see the example here https://jsfiddle.net/fov47eny/

Comment: Thanks. I’ve added your code, however id doesn’t clear the interval when I click "next” button. Maybe it has to do with the complexity of code on the page..here it is http://rogercastillo.org/responsive3/home ..the site is not optimised yet, wait around 7 seconds for the page to load. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @DmitryRa I can't open this url. did you tried the jsfiddle? it's working :/

Comment: It’s quite hard to see what is going on in jsfiddle, the log shows when button clicked, but it doesn’t show if the interval is active or not.. =)